# How do I build a dplyr summarize statement programmatically?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to do some dplyr programming and having trouble. I'd like to `group_by` an arbitrary number of variables (thus, `across`), and then `summarize` based on arbitrary length (but all the same length) vectors of:

- The column to apply the function to
- The function to apply
- The name of the new column

So, like in a `map` or `apply` statement, I want to execute code that ends up looking like:

```
data %>%
  group_by(group_column) %>%
  summarize(new_name_1 = function_1(column_1),
  summarize(new_name_2 = function_2(column_2))
```

Here's an example of what I want and my best shot so far. I know I can use the `names` argument to clean those up if I use across, but I'm not confident that across is the correct way. Finally, I'll be applying this to fairly large dataframes, so I'd rather not calculate the extra columns.

**Desired result**

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(across(c("cyl", "carb"))) %>%
  summarise(across(c("disp", "hp"), list(mean = mean, sd = sd))) %>%
  select(cyl, carb, disp_mean, hp_sd)
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'cyl' (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 4
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>     cyl  carb disp_mean hp_sd
#>   <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     4     1      91.4 16.1 
#> 2     4     2     117.  24.9 
#> 3     6     1     242.   3.54
#> 4     6     4     164.   7.51
#> 5     6     6     145   NA   
#> 6     8     2     346.  14.4 
#> 7     8     3     276.   0   
#> 8     8     4     406.  21.7 
#> 9     8     8     301   NA
```

**What I get**

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(across(c("cyl", "carb"))) %>%
  summarise(across(c("disp", "hp"), list(mean = mean, sd = sd)))
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'cyl' (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 6
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>     cyl  carb disp_mean disp_sd hp_mean hp_sd
#>   <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     4     1      91.4   21.4     77.4 16.1 
#> 2     4     2     117.    27.1     87   24.9 
#> 3     6     1     242.    23.3    108.   3.54
#> 4     6     4     164.     4.39   116.   7.51
#> 5     6     6     145     NA      175   NA   
#> 6     8     2     346.    43.4    162.  14.4 
#> 7     8     3     276.     0      180    0   
#> 8     8     4     406.    57.8    234   21.7 
#> 9     8     8     301     NA      335   NA
```

Answer (score 6):

With different functions on different columns, an option is to use `collap` from `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
collap(mtcars, ~ cyl + carb, custom = list(fmean = 4, fsd = 5))
```

-output

```
cyl   disp        hp carb
1   4  91.38 16.133815    1
2   4 116.60 24.859606    2
3   6 241.50  3.535534    1
4   6 163.80  7.505553    4
5   6 145.00        NA    6
6   8 345.50 14.433757    2
7   8 275.80  0.000000    3
8   8 405.50 21.725561    4
9   8 301.00        NA    8
```

---

Or the index can be dynamically generated with `match`

```
collap(mtcars, ~ cyl + carb, custom = list(fmean =
   match('disp', names(mtcars)), fsd = match('hp', names(mtcars))))
```

---

With `tidyverse`, an option is to loop over the column names of interest and the functions in `map2` and do a join later

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
map2(c("disp", "hp"), c("mean", "sd"), ~
   mtcars %>%
      group_by(across(c('cyl', 'carb'))) %>% 
      summarise(across(all_of(.x), match.fun(.y), 
         .names = str_c("{.col}_", .y)), .groups = 'drop')) %>% 
    reduce(inner_join)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 x 4
    cyl  carb disp_mean hp_sd
  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
1     4     1      91.4 16.1 
2     4     2     117.  24.9 
3     6     1     242.   3.54
4     6     4     164.   7.51
5     6     6     145   NA   
6     8     2     346.  14.4 
7     8     3     276.   0   
8     8     4     406.  21.7 
9     8     8     301   NA
```

Comment: The `tidyverse`-solution is great. I couldn't figure it out. :-)

Comment: Thank you, this is a great solution!

Answer (score 1):

I have a package on github [{dplyover}](https://github.com/TimTeaFan/dplyover)

which can help with this kind of tasks. In this case we could use `over2` to
loop over two character vectors simultaniously. The first vector contains the
variable names as string, which is why we have to wrap `.x` in `sym()` when
applying a function to it. The second vector contains the function names,
which we use as `.y` in a `do.call`. `over2` creates the desired names automatically.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(dplyover) # https://github.com/TimTeaFan/dplyover

mtcars %>%
  group_by(across(c("cyl", "carb"))) %>%
  summarise(over2(c("disp", "hp"),
                  c("mean", "sd"),
                  ~ do.call(.y, list(sym(.x)))
                  ))

#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'cyl'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 9 x 4
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>     cyl  carb disp_mean hp_sd
#>   <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     4     1      91.4 16.1 
#> 2     4     2     117.  24.9 
#> 3     6     1     242.   3.54
#> 4     6     4     164.   7.51
#> 5     6     6     145   NA   
#> 6     8     2     346.  14.4 
#> 7     8     3     276.   0   
#> 8     8     4     406.  21.7 
#> 9     8     8     301   NA
```

An alternative way building on the same logic is to use `purrr::map2`. However,
here we have to put some effort into creating vectors with the desired names.

```r
library(purrr)

# setup vectors and names
myfuns <- c("mean", "sd")
myvars <- c("disp", "hp") %>%
  set_names(., paste(., myfuns, sep = "_"))

mtcars %>%
  group_by(across(c("cyl", "carb"))) %>%
  summarise(map2(myvars,
                 myfuns,
                 ~ do.call(.y, list(sym(.x)))
                 ) %>% bind_cols()
  )

#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'cyl'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 9 x 4
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>     cyl  carb disp_mean hp_sd
#>   <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     4     1      91.4 16.1 
#> 2     4     2     117.  24.9 
#> 3     6     1     242.   3.54
#> 4     6     4     164.   7.51
#> 5     6     6     145   NA   
#> 6     8     2     346.  14.4 
#> 7     8     3     276.   0   
#> 8     8     4     406.  21.7 
#> 9     8     8     301   NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>